# Efficient way to find customer entries in two large streams of data

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-spark

If I have a data stream that gives me 10 million records a day (Stream A), and another that gives me 1 billion a day (Stream B) what is an efficient way to see if there is an overlap in the data?

More specifically, if there is a customer in Stream A who visits a webpage, and that same customer visits a different webpage in Stream B, how can I tell that the customer visited both webpages?

My initial thought was to put the records into a relational database and do a join, but I know that is very inefficient.

What is a more efficient way to do this? How would I be able to do this using a tool like Hadoop or Spark?

Comment: Do you need it to create some stats for every user for or just get the number of distinct users for both websites?

Comment: Just get a list of users who have visited both sites

Comment: Oh, I just thought that if you want to get approximate the count of users visiting both sites you can try HyperLogLog - https://github.com/twitter/algebird, but that's probably not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

A join should be an efficient way of dealing with this. You should have both data sets ordered, or an index on the CustomerID (and the index would be ordered by CustomerID). Because of the indexing, the SQL engine would know that the sets are ordered and should be able to do the join very efficiently.

If you're only looking for instances where the CustomerID is in both, it might be a SQL query along the lines of:

```
Select Distinct A.CustomerID 
From A 
  Inner Join B 
    on A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID
```